# SQL Where Date Condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I want get sales data on between the two dates but it does not work correctly SQL query.

[image: saledate column]

```
  if($_GET['startdate'])
  {
    $startdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['startdate']));
  }
  else
  {
    $startdate = 'NOW()';
  }
  if($_GET['enddate'])
  {
    $enddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['enddate']));
  }
  else
  {
    $enddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 month'));
  }
  $db->setTrace('true');

  $sales = $db->rawQuery('SELECT * from sales where (saledate BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND deletestat = ?',  [$startdate, $enddate, '0']);
  print_r($db->trace);
```

I am using [joshcam/mySQLi](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#initialization) class for sql queries.

How to get data on between the two dates?

Comment: A) What results do you get? B) What's the problem? You don't say what "work correctly" means or even what's not working like it should.

Comment: specifically explain are you getting on error or wrong result?

Comment: @Jagrati I don't get the error or wrong result. Query result return null.

Comment: @tadman 
A) I want to get data between two dates. Sample: 10.09.2016 between 10.10.2016 datas.

B)  It doesn't receive data within the specified date range. Although data dated 18.09.2016.

Comment: Are you sure your dates are being formatted correctly? They should be in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` which hopefully is what your `date` code emits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql between function works different than you expect.

> The between function expect the first parameter to be the min value en the second parameter to be the max value. See the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

If you change this line:

```
$sales = $db->rawQuery('SELECT * from sales where (saledate BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND deletestat = ?',  [$startdate, $enddate, '0']);
```

To this:

```
$sales = $db->rawQuery('SELECT * from sales where (saledate BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND deletestat = ?',  [$enddate, $startdate, '0']);
```

Than it will work.

Comment: It did not work. Trace result; `SELECT identityno, name, salesprice, restprice, commission, comissier, profit, saledate, type from sales where (saledate BETWEEN '2016-09-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-10 00:00:00') AND deletestat = '0'` but not get data between date

Comment: As you can see, the min and max value is wrong. You should switch that. I think the problem is you have  - 1 month when there is no date. But when you add a date you can have maybe a date in the future.

Comment: There's data to date 18/09/2016 but not get data

Comment: can you try this sql via phpmyadmin or mysql cli and see if there is any output: `SELECT identityno, name, salesprice, restprice, commission, comissier, profit, saledate, type from sales where (saledate BETWEEN  '2016-08-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-19 00:00:00') AND deletestat = '0'`